# How to give cast shadow to text in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want cast shadow on text like this in flutter -

[image]

I tried this code but it's not what I like want

````
```
Text(
  '2',
  style: TextStyle(
    shadows: <Shadow>[
      Shadow(
        offset: Offset(10.0, 10.0),
        blurRadius: 3.0,
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),

```
````